# Hide/remove 'add to cart' button on shop page for one product only

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to hide or remove the ADD TO CART button on the shop page for a single product only? This would be in order to force the user to click to the single product page, where they are to "build" or customize their product.

I tried the following line of code, but it didn't get the job done:

```
#product-3093 .products-grid .button.btn-cart {
display: none;}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to do it using CSS then better share your site so we can look at the code.